# HTML, CSS, and JavaScript Code Injection into an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe

It only allows you to inject CSS and HTML.

How could you inject JavaScript into the iFrame?  I tried changing:

```
    styleTag = $('<style></style>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));
```

to

```
    styleTag = $('<script></script>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));
```

but it didn't work.  Could you help?

The demo link is http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/1089_iframe/iframe/iframe.html

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the code is in fact working.

Unfortunately, what you'll find in most browsers is that it doesn't update the DOM to reflect it.

If you provided a src= on the tag, you would however be able to confirm it was loading the script via a network window that most browsers provide to their developers.

But again, you wouldn't likely see it in the DOM.

Also, you can create the tag via standard javascript and attach to an event to indicate it was loaded. With standard Javascript this would look something like:

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.onreadystatechange= function () {
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
        alert("loaded!");
    }
}
script.onload= helper;
script.src= 'helper.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

I'm not sure off-hand if there is a 100% native jQuery match to this.

Comment: actually, when I changed it to <script> from <style> in jsfiddle, it stopped at the point where I changed it and wrote out the rest of my code into the html as text